# Nodejs Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a problem with nodejs,
when I want to make a post with an image, I have an error message "Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined"

I do not see where my error is, can you enlighten me

this is my middleware multer :

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES = {
  'image/jpg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/gif': 'gif',
  
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {  
    const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
  }
});


module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('image');
```

in my app.js

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

in my post.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const multer = require('../middleware/multer-config')
const postCtrl = require('../controllers/postController');

router.post('/new', auth, multer, postCtrl.createPost);
```

in my postController.js

```
exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
    
    // Create post in database
    console.log(req.body)
    const article = {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        userId: req.body.userId,
        picture: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`
    };
    Post.create(article)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Article."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Where the property is used... req.file.filename

Comment: here : filename: (req, file, callback) => {  
    const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

I guess that problem is here

```
picture: `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`
```

May be your request have no property "file",
If you are sending id in body, it must be like this - req.body.file.filename

It is better to check your request.

Comment: i try with `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.body.file.filename}` not working

Comment: can you write here your requests body?

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging req.file in controller. If it is undefined, there will be two probabilities

1. Image is not send in the request
2. It is not stored by multer

If it is not stored, i did faced the same issue creating filename with Date.now() is not working, you can try this

```
name + '-' + Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6) + '-' + Math.random().toString().slice(2, 6) + extension
```

Comment: i try a console.log(req.file) it's undefined, ans image is not send

Answer (score 0):

**In my case:**

Removing `"transform-react-jsx-source"` from the **.babelrc** fixed this problem.

This is how my **.babelrc** file looks after removing `"transform-react-jsx-source"`:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": []
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```